# Add a period at end of paragraph

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need a command to add a period (full stop) to the end of a paragraph. I have tried the following command:

```
 sed '/ +$ / s/$/ ./' $FILENAME
```

but it does not work!!

Comment: @FredrikPihl that's the same command that i tried and does not do what i need ?

Comment: Copy-paste-error, that's why I removed it

Comment: What's a paragraph in your case? Is it a line, or is it a set of lines separated by a blank line?

Comment: a set of lines separated by a blank line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS=".\n\n" 1 file
```

This redefines the input record separator to be empty, so that awk reads blank-line separated paragraphs as a single record. It sets the output record separator to be a dot and 2 newlines. The actual awk program, `1` simple prints each record.

One side-effect is that any consecutive blank lines will be collapsed into a single blank line.

---

OK, sheesh

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '{sub(/\.?$/,".")} 1'
```

In action: (piping through `cat -n` just to point out the newlines)

```
echo -e "a.\n\nb\nc\n\n\nd" | 
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '{sub(/\.?$/,".")} 1' |
cat -n
```

```
 1  a.
 2  
 3  b
 4  c.
 5  
 6  d.
 7
```

There's an extra newline at the end, due to the ORS.

---

And, as a bonus, here's a bit of Perl that preserves the inter-paragraph spacing:

```
echo -e "a.\n\nb\nc\n\n\nd" | perl -0777 -pe 's/\.?(\n(\n+|$))/.$1/g' | cat -n
```

```
 1  a.
 2  
 3  b
 4  c.
 5  
 6  
 7  d.
```

Comment: You done it again, I got lost in http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html and missed the period in the `ORS`-part... +1 But, if I run in on my example-text I get an extra period at the end of the first sentence...

Comment: @FredrikPihl: Indeed: Glenn's otherwise elegant and concise solution _unconditionally_ appends a `.`, even if a paragraph already ends in one - just a constraint to be aware of.

Comment: While this works great (with the noted constraints), what baffles me is: `RS=""`. I understand `RS="\n\n+"`, which also works, but why does `RS=""` work? Why are two or more consecutive `\n` chars. treated differently than the paragraph-interior ones and cause record separation?

Comment: I'm not at a computer now but to make it conditional 1) take the dot out of ORS 2) use the awk body (something like) `{sub(".?$",".")}1`

Comment: @mklement0 probably because it's a common use case so the designers of awk wanted to make it easy

Comment: fail, same issue as Birei, will still attach dot even the paragraph has dot in end.

Answer (score 1):

Not very good, but it seems to work...

```
$ cat input
This is a paragraph with some text. Some random text that is not really important.

This is another paragraph with some text.
However this sentence is still in the same paragraph

$ tr '\n' '@' < input | sed 's/\([^.]\)@@/\1.@@/g' | tr '@' '\n'
This is a paragraph with some text. Some random text that is not really important.

This is another paragraph with some text.
However this sentence is still in the same paragraph.
```

Comment: it does not work !! . also i cant understand anything from this command !!

Comment: @Hassan -- it just replaces every newline with a `@` with the result that everything is one one line, Then I simply do a replace for the pattern `character-that is not a period, followed by 2 @@` to include a period. And the last `tr` command put the newlines back again. The mighty Glen Jackman shows how to really do it!

Answer (score 1):

Using sed.

```
 sed  ':loop;$!{N;b loop};s/[^\.]$/&./;s/\([^\.]\)\(\n[ \t]*\n\)/\1.\2/g' file
```

explanation

`:loop;$!{N;b loop}` will save all the lines in pattern space delimited by newline.
`s/[^.]$/&./`  will add . if last paragraph doesn't have dot in end.
`s/\([^\.]\)\(\n[ \t]*\n\)/\1.\2/g`  will add dot before \n \n, which is identify as new paragraph.

Comment: +1 for preserving the original number of blank lines between paragraphs and correctly dealing with already .-terminated paragraphs (unlike @glennjackman's more concise and readable solution). On platforms where -rfor extended regexes is available (e.g., Linux), we get the more readable: `sed -r ':loop;$!{N;b loop};s/[^.]$/&./;s/([^.])(\n[ \t]*\n)/\1.\2/g'` file. To make it work on OSX (note the spliced-in newline literals): `sed -E ':loop'$'\n''$!{N;b loop'$'\n''};s/[^.]$/&./;s/([^.])(\n[ \t]*\n)/\1.\2/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

1. Accumulate 'paragraphs' in the hold space. Keep accumulating as long as 
   the input line contains any non-space character(s).
2. When you get a blank/empty line, assume you have an accumulated paragraph. Swap the current (blank) line with the hold space. Replace the last non-space character in the pattern space (which is now the "paragraph" you were accumulating) with itself followed by a dot, unless that character is a dot. Print the result.

I think this does it:

```
$ cat test
this is a test line. one-line para

this is a test line. one-line para. with period.

this is a
two line para-
graph with dot.

this is a
two-line paragraph
with no dot

also works on last
line of file
$ sed -n \
    -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/{x;s/\([^.[:space:]][[:space:]]*\)$/\1./;p;n;}' \
    -e '/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]/H' \
    test

this is a test line. one-line para.

this is a test line. one-line para. with period.

this is a
two line para-
graph with dot.

this is a
two-line paragraph
with no dot.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed "s/[[:alpha:]]\+[^\.]$/\./" $FILENAME
```

Comment: also i try it , it's put stop point on an empty line !!  also if the line has alread stop point , it will add another stop point !

Comment: Can you please post some test text and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

A pure [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution using the *hold space* to save all lines from a paragraph and append a period just before printing:

```
sed -ne '
    ## Append current line to "hold space".
    H
    ## When found an empty line, get content of "hold space", remove leading
    ## newline added by "H" command, append a period at the end and print.
    ## Also, clean "hold space" to save following paragraph.
    /^$/ { g; s/^\n//; s/\(.*\)\(\n\)/\1.\2/; p; s/^.*$//; h; b }
    ## Last line is a bit special, it has no following blank line but it is also
    ## an end of paragraph. It is similar to previous case but simpler.
    $ { x; s/^\n//; s/$/./; p }
' infile
```

Assuming an `infile` with content:

```
one
two

three

four
five
six
```

It yields:

```
one
two.

three.

four
five
six.
```

Comment: man , it's seem that youre script solve my problem , but that type of code , i never see it , could you explaine me what is that ?

Comment: @Hassan: It's `sed` commands with comments interleaved. For better explanation of each instruction look at the manual.

Comment: yes , i google it , and i understand it , thank you for youre effort

Comment: Looks fail, if the paragraph has dot in end already, the sed command  still adds one more dot after it.